Logging Deleted and Edited Messages
I'm making a server bot for my server and I want to log all message deletions and edits. It will log into a log channel for staff to see. In the log channel, I want to have the message show what was deleted or what was before the message edit and what was after the edit of the message. Displaying the deleted message is working fine but i couldn't figure out How to do same on message edit.
This is How i made displaying deleted message part.
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message:discord.Message):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Deleted Message Content and Origin")
        embed.add_field(name="Origin", value=f"{message.author.mention}", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Origin Channel", value=f"{message.channel.mention}", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Content", value=f"{message.content}", inline=False)
        log_channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.channels, name="logging")
        
        await log_channel.send(embed=embed)


on_message_edit requires two parameters, one will be the message before the edit and the other will be the message after the edit. If you're in a class, you need the self as well.
An example:
@commands.Cog.listener() # or @bot.listen()/@bot.event if you're not inside a cog
async def on_message_edit(self, before: discord.Message, after: discord.Message): 
    # before will be the message before and after will be the message after edit.
    # use before.content to get content before and after.content to get content after


Documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message_edit

